# Ubuntu 20.04 | Google Chrome doesn't Automatically Restore Tabs

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

Goal: I want all my previous tabs appear when I launch Google Chrome automatically.

When I restart off `Ubuntu 20.04`, and launch **Google Chrome** a `Restore` button appears.

Is there a way to have it do so automatically without being told?

I followed this [article](https://workona.com/blog/how-to-restore-tabs-chrome/#:%7E:text=Enable%20setting%20to%20restore%20Google%20Chrome%20tabs%20after%20restart&text=restarts%2C%20it%27s%20easy%3A-,Open%20the%20Chrome%20menu%20), and still no difference.

> Enable setting to restore Google Chrome tabs after restart If you’re
> looking for a way to restore all tabs when Chrome restarts, it’s easy:
>
> Open the Chrome menu (click the 3-dot menu in the upper-right corner
> of Chrome)
>
> Click Settings Scroll to the On Startup section at the
> bottom of the page
>
> Click to enable the setting Continue where you left
> off

Comment: how do you close google chrome? Shutting down while chrome is open may result in it "crashing," and a "restore" is the only option. What happens if you close chrome using the "x" in the corner, and open it again?

Comment: Whenever I've it open but I Power Off machine: `unexpected`

Comment: what happens if you close chrome normally, and then reopen it?

Comment: Ahh. Everything appears, without asking to `Restore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429404)  in Chromium/Google Chrome where shutting down or restarting the device with Chromium open results in Chromium thinking it crashed. This means that it doesn't shut down and save state properly, and instead needs to "recover" from the crash.

You can try making sure to close Chrome normally before shutting down. Otherwise, there doesn't seem to be a good workaround.

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420 chrome auto-saves as well, which is how it is able to recover from a crash. The problem is that it thinks it crashed, which the Chromium people most likely have to fix